# How to start a container automatically in boot2docker on boot?

Tags: containers, docker, boot, boot2docker

I'd like to start a reverse-proxy in my boot2docker VM when I run `boot2docker up`.

What's the preferred way to do so?

I thought about creating a startup script in the host-vm, but it would be nicer if I could add a set of startup scripts to boot2docker on my Mac, since these would not be erased when using another host image.

I've looked through the options of boot2docker and searched the web, but found nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the host image, then maybe you can have another script that wrap `boot2docker up` and `docker start proxy...` together.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work, but I was also wondering if there's no build in solution.